# Suffix Tree check existence of P pattern before k position

Tags: algorithm, bioinformatics, suffix-tree

I need to design an algorithm that given a **T string of n length**, after a process **O(n)**, for every **string P of m length** and a **k** value between 1 to n, to checks in **O(m)** time, if **P appears on T before k position**, only using **Suffix Tree**.

Unfortunately there are not any good bioinformatics books with fair examples and practical methodologies. Dan Gusfield book does not offer a solution manual.

Comment: Please provide at least a coarse outline of the inputs and outputs as example. Every bit of mental workload which you spare your audience improves your chances to get an answer. [MCVE]

Comment: It's an engineering task with pseudo-code. It's like a draft, there is not an example with inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessing: after constructing the suffix tree, use DFS to label each node with the minimum index of the suffixes that appear in its descendants.

Query: descend in the suffix tree on the links indicated by P, threshold the node value constructed above.